# redirect css and img directory to sub-folders

Tags: php, .htaccess

i want to redirect the Urls to be clean using htaccess

for example this is the original url `localhost/stories.php` , i want it to be `localhost/stories`
and `localhost/story1.php` to `localhost/stories/story1` .. etc.
i have made it but the images and styles doesn't work because `css,img,js` folders aren't in the correct place.
what can i do to redirect css and img folders considering the `css , img` have sub-folders

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^stories$ stories.php [L]
RewriteRule ^stories/story1$ story1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^stories/story2$ story2.php [L]
```

Comment: What exactly do you need for css and img paths? What are their actual working paths?

Comment: localhost/css,localhost/img .. this is for example

Comment: That only answers half of my comment.